# E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, exoplayer

I am trying the play the video by the exo Player, but it gives me this error:-

> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
>                                                                                  InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404

This is my Activity Class :-

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoRendererEventListener {
    private String mVideoUrl;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private static final String TAG = "AMAN";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    if (getIntent() != null)
        mVideoUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("VideoUrl");




    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);


    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();


    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
    simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);


    simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();


    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);



    Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse(mVideoUrl);

    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeterA);

    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();


    MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
    final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);




   player.prepare(loopingSource);
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: by the error, it seems that the content you're try to load doesn't exist. If you're sure that exists, maybe the path/url you're using is wrong or the application is being blocked to reach the resource

Comment: @ElmerDantas Dear when i hit the url in the browser then its playing...but in my application its not working..according to you if the url is incorrect then its also not working in browser..this is my url :-                                                          https://tgconnect.co.in/tgtech/uploads/video/100 crore ka Qtiyapa - Bollywood Qtiyapa (ft. Anurag Kashyap).mp4

Comment: I'm not a Android developer but I noticed your response error code: 404. So for some reason your application is not able to find the resource you're trying to access. Why? unfortunately I don't know but I'm sure that with some google you'll be able to figure out.

Comment: Its actually not from the exoplayer try to fix your SSL handshake error,

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this error yet?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327704/3404480

Answer (score 0):

You must use the "final" modifier for your link.

```
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    final String VIDEO_URL = getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");

    playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo_player);
    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "appname"));
    MediaSource videoSource  = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(VIDEO_URL));
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}`
```