# com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404

Tags: java, android, ssl, webview

Ok, so I am going to play a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCjIrEQCzWM) through ExoPlayer by calling the playing procedure using Javascript Interface...

The problem is, when I try to open the video using ExoPlayer, it does try to open the link than it didn't play, when I see the Logcat, I got the error

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:300)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:156)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I tried adding final to the string which contains the video URL, like suggested by the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795420/e-exoplayerimplinternal-source-error-com-google-android-exoplayer2-upstream-htt) , but still get the same error

So, I try to scroll up the Logcat and I found SSL error

```
SSL_connect:error exit in 3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
```

Then I try using the solution in [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20488#issuecomment-409535369) but still got the same error

My code

**ExoPlayer.java**

```java
public class ExoPlayer extends AppCompatActivity{
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    public static String url;
    public Context context;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

        final String video = getIntent().getStringExtra("video");

        iniExoPlayer(video);
    }


    public void iniExoPlayer(String url){
        Log.d("owo",url);
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_player);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        //#Default Data Source use this
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, "app-name"));
        MediaSource videoSource = new SsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
            simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
         }
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <base includeSubdomains="true">MainUrl</base>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

</network-security-config>
```

And here's my [Logcat](https://pastebin.com/vAeR0g7U)

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I converted the video player to VLC

Answer (score 3):

Check your URL link. because there is no video on that link

I solved by changing URL

Comment: If no video or audio not found then how can I handle this? It's looping. Trying and trying.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the media URL may not be having any video in it. Try with a different URL and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).