# how to fix E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

When I try to Play audio form server exoplayer given error `"Response Code:400"` on Android Lolipop and Marsmallow but same code playing song on Android upper Version.

`E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:848) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:317) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

Comment: did u found the solution? i have the same error

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting this error because of your web client in API ~30

Use code snippet below to allow URL

```
new WebViewClient() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(Classname.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
        // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
        onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Prashant - where you did add this snippet to allow the URL?

Comment: It's just API issue, TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M). will fix it in my case. Is it not working now? In which API level?

Answer (score -3):

As you can see from the log of android studio
**E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.**

This Error when ExoPlayer Didn't get the Source or Video URL. So check your video url before loading the player using log.